# How to separate data from this stringify object in angularjs and view it in html

Tags: angularjs

I would like to separate data from this stringify object.

```
var str = JSON.stringify({u:'1234lkiw34532350YYmsddeeee1', m:'9898989898',v : [{t:1,n:'AP07BT8789'},{t:3,n:'AP07BT8076'},{t:3,n:'AP07BT8789'}]});
var obj=JSON.parse(str);
```

> **Notations Meaning**
>       t -type
>       u-userid
>       m -mobile
>       v- vehicle
>       1 - 2wheeler
>       2- 4 wheeler
>       3 - bus

I have separated this to show you

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? In other words, you have parsed the json, now what is 'not' working for you?

Comment: after parsing i need each and every data to be displayed in html page..
userid-1234
Mobile No:98989898
Type Two Wheeler
Number - AP

Comment: Is it an angular or angularjs application? Also, how do you want the data to be displayed (the structure for showing it)?

Comment: angularjs application.
Html form..like showing the details..

Answer (score -1):

From what I have understood from your comments, assuming it is an angularjs app,

> controller

```
var str = JSON.stringify({u:'1234lkiw34532350YYmsddeeee1', m:'9898989898',v : [{t:1,n:'AP07BT8789'},{t:3,n:'AP07BT8076'},{t:3,n:'AP07BT8789'}]});
$scope.customer = JSON.parse(str);
$scope.typesMap = { 1: '2 wheeler', 2: '4 wheeler', 3: 'Bus' };
```

> corresponding template

```
<div>User Id: {{ customer.u }} </div>
<div>Mobile No: {{ customer.m }} </div>
<div>Vehicle details: </div>
<ul ng-repeat="vehicle in customer.v">
 <li>Type: {{ typesMap[vehicle.t] }}</li>
 <li>Number: {{ vehicle.n }}</li>
</ul>
```

Above is the basic code snippet with which you can show the corresponding values to the template page. Might need to restructure or style them to your liking.